# Having Trouble Install npx Create-react-app my-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

these are the errors I received, it might be something npm not sure.
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

Please help I tried Np reinstall, but I am unsure where this issue lies.

Comment: also tried reinstalling node.js

Comment: So [actually show what you're doing](/help/how-to-ask). Tell folks what you were trying to do, then show them the actual command you issued, with the error that resulted in (with some code markup because that's not plain post text), and then talk about what you think that error means and what you already looked up/(re)searched. Right now, your post is incomplete.

Comment: if that is the command you typed : npx Create-react-app my-app 
then there's a type in Create, it should be all small letters

Answer (score 0):

First install nodejs if you haven't